# Google Scholar Organic Results API Entire Snippet?

Tags: google-scholar, serpapi

I was wondering how I could get the whole snippet?. It seems to cut off half of the abstract of any queried research paper.

Example Python Code:

```
from serpapi import GoogleSearch

params = {
  "engine": "google_scholar",
  "q": "Delving deep into rectifiers: Surpassing human-level performance on ImageNet classification",
  "api_key": "key"
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

print(results['organic_results'][0]['snippet'])
```

OUTPUT:
Rectified activation units (rectifiers) are essential for state-of-the-art neural networks. In this work, we study rectifier neural networks for image classification from two aspects. First, we propose a Parametric Rectified Linear Unit (PReLU) that generalizes the traditional rectified unit. PReLU improves model fitting with nearly zero extra computational cost and little overfitting risk. Second, we derive a robust initialization method that particularly considers the rectifier nonlinearities. This method enables us to train extremely deep rectified models …